# I was solving a regex problem that matches the phone numbers I wrote a code but that's not working properly

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation

I am learning regex so I was trying to write a regex pattern that will match phone number and it's worked with many cases but not with every case. I want to know what mistake I did here

it fails with this input
1
87456985211 ------output(YES)

The code which I tried is

```
import re
for i in range(int(input())):
    print("YES" if re.findall(r'(7|8|9)\d{9}$', input()) else 'NO')
```

Comment: Use an anchor and a character class `^[789]\d{9}$`

Comment: This tool (no association), https://www.debuggex.com/ will help you considerably in your quest to get working regex - as will this;  http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
^(7|8|9)\d{9}$
```

Without the caret at the start, 7456985211 also matches the criteria.